# lint warning that val() and text() are called incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-lint

I have:

```
 TotalPrice = parseInt(TotalPrice*100)/100;
 $('input[name=EstimatedPrice]').val(TotalPrice);
 $('#EstimatedPriceDisplay').text(TotalPrice);
```

and I'm getting two warnings from lint.

1. val() called incorrectly
2. text() called incorrectly.

I was able to eliminate the text() called incorrectly error by doing the following:

```
$('#EstimatedPriceDisplay').text('' + TotalPrice);
```

But that seems kinda kludgy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to support IE <5.5? If not, try to use [the `.toFixed()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp), which returns a string and rounded to the specified decimal place.

```
 TotalPrice = TotalPrice.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Ooh.  I hate making decisions about who should get the rep!

Answer (score 2):

Doing:

```
$('#EstimatedPriceDisplay').text('' + TotalPrice);
```

should be fine or you can use the `toString` method:

```
$('#EstimatedPriceDisplay').text(TotalPrice.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're reusing the variable, I'd make it a String when the value is assigned.

```
TotalPrice = (Math.round(TotalPrice*100)/100) + '';
```

This way you only need to do it once, and it is not cluttering `.val()` and `.text()`

```
$('input[name=EstimatedPrice]').val(TotalPrice);
$('#EstimatedPriceDisplay').text(TotalPrice);
```

**EDIT:** Changed to `Math.round()` to get proper up/down rounding.

Comment: Oh!
I never thought .val() wanted a string parameter!
I think my old school thinking is getting in my way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[name=EstimatedPrice]').val(TotalPrice.toFixed(2));
 $('#EstimatedPriceDisplay').text(TotalPrice.toFixed(2));
```